# Convert rjs to js.erb in rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, rjs

How to do I convert an rjs file to js.erb

Just renaming doesn't work in my case

This is my old code(works well with rails 2 app)

```
page.replace_html(
 "overlay" , 
  :partial => @path_resolver.resolve_template(
                :tmpl_name => 'cmn/popup/shared/show_popup',
                :partial => true
            ),
:object => @content_data
```

)

I changed the code to

```
  page.replace_html(
"overlay" , 
("<%= escape_javascript(render(
:partial => @path_resolver.resolve_template(
                :tmpl_name => 'cmn/popup/shared/show_popup',
                :partial => true
            ))) %>"),

 :locals => {:object => @content_data }
```

)

Now I got an syntax error in firebug like

```
 SyntaxError: syntax error

 :locals => {:object => @content_data }
```

If i pass the object code as **:object => @content_data** (without using locals)

im getting another error

```
 syntax error
 :object => @content_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

We need to use `Element.update` in place of `page.replace_html`.

The new code looks like:

```
Element.update (
  "overlay" ,
  "<%= escape_javascript(render(
            :partial => @path_resolver.resolve_template(
            :tmpl_name => '../shared/show_popup',
            :partial => true,

             :object => @content_data 
           ))) %>"
)
```